# Lineal functions with Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f, g\in O(\mathbb{C})$ (holomorphed in $\mathbb{C}$) and $k\in\mathbb{R}^{*}$ such that $Re(f(z))\leq kRe(g(z))$, for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that there are constant $a$ y $b$ such that $f(z)=ag(z)+b$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

My attempts:

I know that if $f$ is entire and $Re(f(z))\leq M$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is constant so I don't know if I could use this statement with $f(z)-g(z)$ or if there is another way to show it.

Comment: what is $\mathbb R^*?$

Answer (score 1):

Try $h(z):= \exp(f(z)-kg(z))$ and use the fact that $|\exp z| = \exp(\text{Re}(z))$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $k\in \mathbb R ,$ $\text { Re }(f-kg) = \text { Re }f-k \text { Re }g\le 0$ everywhere. Now use the result you already know.